# About project using Node.js with openCV

Tags: node.js

I am planning a project CCTV system using Node.js and openCV, WebGL.
Would you please take a look at my plan and find flaw or give me advice?

My plan is: Entire system consists of 3 types of host, CCTV-server-watchmen. Numbers of each host may be (more than 10)-1-3? CCTV take a video and send it to the server. The server identifies persons in the video, and analyzes who this person is and where he or she is(using OpenCV). Finally, watchmen can seize entire status of field he or she manages(map drawn by webGL helps it). I will use node.js as network method.

I have a few issues about my plan.

1. Is it efficient to use Node.js as video data transmitter?
   Basic concept of Node.js is single-thread, so maybe large data like video does not fit to it. But, count of CCTV and watchmen is limited and fixed(It is system for closed intranet)
2. Is there any method can replace Node.js?
   I will not replace openCV and WebGL. But Node.js could matters. At the beginning of planning, I was finding other means for networking between C/C++ program and web-browser. Honestly, I got failed at school-project last year. One of problems that I can't find solution was "How to send/receive data between C program installed at Raspberry Pi and web Browser". I chose Node.js as method this project, but also heard other means of Qt, DB, CGI. Is there a better way?

Thank you for reading it.

Comment: This is not a question suitable for stackoverflow, stackoverflow is about code not application design. If I were you I would try to avoid sending the video data over the network and do the OpenCV stuff on the clients itself then transfer only the result, this way the application is scalable and intranet bandwidth is saved. As to your second question, Qt is a UI framework, CGI is a protocol for web-servers and DB(as in Database?) seriously?! Maybe this is due to the language barrier but do you even know what you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry. I will be more careful next time. 

As you said, It is better to make client compute data by itself. About 2nd question, I heard Qt provides classes about network, and openCV library. and about DB and CGI I just heard these, but don't know where to start study about these. Thank you for answer.